# Динамическое создание элементов Delphi

Tags: delphi

Имеется XML в котором описан интерфейс, например

```
<toolbar name="Sale" align="top">
    <button>
        <name>OpenCheck</name>
    </button>
</toolbar>
```

можно ли на его основе создать интерфейс (я знаю, что можно)
без использования if\case 
т.е не

```
if типЭлемента='toolbar' then element := TToolbar.Create(владелец) 
else if типЭлемента='button' then element := TButton.Create(владелец)
```

а более универсальный метод ?!

Answer (score 2):

Можно завести свой массив соответствий имен классам по типу:

```
lookup: array of record
  xmlName: string; // имя контрола, как в xml
  ctrlClass: TControlClass; // тип класса, (type TControlClass = class of TControl;)
end;
```

в котором прописать соответствия:

```
xmlName     ctrlClass
---------------------
'button'    TButton
'toolbar'   TToolbar
```

и потом при обработке XML находить по строке нужный тип класса в `lookup` и вызывать его конструктор

```
var
  someObject: TControl;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(lookup) do
    if SameText(lookup[i].xmlName, aName) then
      someObject := lookup[i].ctrlClass.Create(..параметры..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно задать соответствие между именами тегов в XML и именами классов в Delphi. Вариантов куча.

- Один Вам подсказали - таблица соответствия (кстати, рекомендую использовать не массив, а `TDictionary<>` - будет значительно быстрее).
- если у Вас типы отличаются только отсутствием буквы Т - использовать функцию `FindClass`или `GetClass`

  ```
  myObject = TComponentClass(FindClass('T' + TagName)).Create;
  ```
- можно объявить свои классы-наследники базовых с нужными именами и зарегистрировать их при помощи функции `RegisterClass()` или `RegisterClasses()`

  ```
  Button = class(TButton);
  Toolbar = class(TToolbar);
  ........
  RegisterClasses([Button, Toolbar]);
  ```

  А потом работать с тем ще `FindClass`

  ```
  myObject = TComponentClass(FindClass(TagName)).Create;
  ```
- перед загрузкой XML натравить на него XSL преобразование, которое заменит теги на нужные, или даже, сформирует из него стандартный dfm который можно будет обработать при помощи `TStream.ReadComponent()`